# "Unable to find element on closed window" error when finding an element after going to another url

Tags: intern, leadfoot

In the test I'm clicking a menu button that go to another page. Afterwards, when I try to find any element on page(The page exists, i can see it), the error 'unable to find element on closed window' keep appearing. I have tried directly getting the url and it works fine. It is when the test clicks a button and goes to another url that I get this error. Can anyone help me to resolve this in intern?

*I'm using webdriver IEDriver 32bit, against IE11*

**Code :**

```
define([
    "intern!object",
    "intern/chai!assert",
    "intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/Element",
    "intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/Server",
    "intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil",
    "intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/keys",
    "require",
    "tests-config"
], function (registerSuite, assert, Element, Server, pollUntil, keys, require, config) {

    registerSuite({

        name: 'Test Suite Form Submissions',

        'Test Submit Form Step 1': function () {
            return this.remote
                .get(config.enter_doctor_url)
                .setFindTimeout(5000)

                .findByXpath("//span[text()='Create Case']")
                // goes to another url after clicking
                .click()
                .end()

               // error occurs here
               .findByXpath("//*[@id=\"js-wizard-eform\"]/fieldset[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/section[1]/label[2]/input")
               .pressKeys("John Doe")
               .end();
        }
    });
});
```

### Console Output, Error:

```
C:\development\xeno1>intern run -w
FAIL: internet explorer 11 on any platform - Test Suite Form Submissions - Test Submit Form Step 1 (6589ms)
NoSuchWindow: [POST http://localhost:44444/wd/hub/session/5aef4686-29ed-40d5-a4e7-bd36982ef034/element / {"using":"xpath","value":"//*[@id=\"js-wiz
ard-eform\"]/fieldset[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/section[1]/label[2]/input"}] Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide
any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'workstation', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=fa
lse, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=
false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:255
50/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 3111becb-07c3-49cf-a151-e0c32a62a76c
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id="js-wizard-eform"]/fieldset[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/section[1]/label[2]/input}
  at runRequest  <node_modules\leadfoot\Session.js:92:40>
  at <node_modules\leadfoot\Session.js:113:39>
  at new Promise  <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:411:3>
  at ProxiedSession._post  <node_modules\leadfoot\Session.js:67:10>
  at ProxiedSession.find  <node_modules\leadfoot\Session.js:1302:15>
  at Command.<anonymous>  <node_modules\leadfoot\Command.js:42:36>
  at <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:393:15>
  at run  <node_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:237:7>
  at <node_modules\dojo\nextTick.ts:44:3>
  at _combinedTickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:67:7>
  at Command.find  <node_modules\leadfoot\Command.js:23:10>
  at Command.prototype.(anonymous function) [as findByXpath]  <node_modules\leadfoot\lib\strategies.js:29:16>
  at Test Doctor Submit Form Step 1 [as test]  <tests\functional\doctor-form-submission.js:44:18>
  at <node_modules\intern\lib\Test.js:191:24>
  at <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:393:15>
  at runCallbacks  <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:11:11>
  at <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:317:4>
  at run  <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:237:7>
  at <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\nextTick.ts:44:3>
  at _combinedTickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:67:7>
1/1 tests failed
1/1 tests failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html#findByXpath) does say

> findByXpath(path: string): Promise.
>
> Gets the first
>   element in the currently active window/frame matching the given XPath
>   selector.

So, if you want to find element in the previous window, you should use `switchToWindow` to make the window you want to find elements be active